# Why my list preference doesn't have a arrow-down icon beside it?

Tags: android

I have a list preference in my preference category, everything looks good except that there is no arrow-down icon beside it.

I changed my theme from light to dark, but no change regarding this arrow icon. I think this is a feature of list preference, but don't know why just not shown!

Any help is great appreciated!

I want to upload images about it, but with no reputation, it is not allowed! what a shame!

I found a list preference example on internet

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/

this example also doesn't have arrow-down icon, exactly the problem I have.

Comment: You can also post a link to a image if you cannot upload.

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/ If you take a look at this example, "Sync frequency" is a list preference, but it doesn't have that down arrow as well. That is the problem I have.

Comment: I tried some sample code on the web, but one one can display arrow-down icon next the list preference. I am thinking does this relate to android version?

Comment: What Android version are you running your app on? The "down arrow" was an Android 1.x/2.x style and is not used on Android 3.0 and higher.

Comment: Hi CommansWare, thank you for your reply. I am running on minSdkVersion="11", which should be Android 3.0(HoneyComb), this might be the reason why. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, they removed the Arrow in HoneyComb (API Level 11).
And never put it back!!
Anyway, there's a trick you can apply to overcome this limitation:
In your ListPreference attributes, add a line like this:

```
android:widgetLayout="@layout/arr_dn"
```

having previously defined a file called arr_dn.xml in your res/layout path, containing the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arr_dn"
/>
```

Of course, you need to put your graphics (I called it arr_dn.png) in your res/drawable path.
I tested under several API levels, including 2.2 and 4.0.3 and it's working well.